# Java method returning arraylist and want to copy this to another arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have one Method that is returning and `Arraylist` (List of Value) and now I want to get this value in to another class in `arraylist`. Here is my example.

```
// ORIGINAL METHOD
public ArrayList groupname(\String userName) {
    .....
    return port.groupname(userName);
}
```

How can I get the above return value in arralist ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I really don't understand which method is returning an Arraylist. BTW, you should mark your methods with return types like List, Set (Interfaces) instead of implementations (ArrayList, etc)

Comment: Hi I have re poste the question at the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943236/java-arraylist-copy-to-another-arraylist                                                              Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
return Arrays.asList(port.groupname(userName));
```

Using standard [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class. The result is immutable, if you need a mutable list:

```
return new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(port.groupname(userName)));
```

BTW consider using generics, Java 1.4 and 5.0 are no longer supported, 6.0 won't be by the end of February.

Answer (score 1):

You can use copy constructor of `ArrayList` as following: `new ArrayList(oldList)`

Comment: I am getting this type of value while retuning value from arralist com.mkyong.ws.ArrayList@3d8e4140 What should I do to display the originla value of the Arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

```
return new ArrayList (Arrays.asList (port.groupname(userName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass arraylist to another class then have a setter method for that class or pass it during the object creation  (constructor)  . Hope this is simpler to implement now